# Hosting a NTFS drive share from Mavericks to Windows 8

Tags: macos, network, smb, ntfs

I have a media server that runs on Mac, and because of this, my drive (which is NTFS) is hosted on the Mac. However, all of my media management is done on my Windows 8 PC that connects to the NTFS drive via an SMB share.

The problem is, when I upgraded from 10.7 to 10.8, Apple seemed to have buggered up the SMB plugins, forcing me to use SMBUP (which works, OK ...)

My question is, if I upgrade my Mac to 10.9, are there any known issues with hosting an SMB share for Windows 8? Ideally, I'd like to remove SMBUP from the picture.

---

(Almost all the information I've found online, is about how to connect to an SMB share, not how to host one.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using TuxeraNTFS for a number of years now to give my Apple computers the ability to read NTFS drives, namely, my bootcamp partition.  Tuxera recently updated their software to support Mavericks and it has been running fine on my iMac and on my Macbook Pro.  However, I've never had to connect to an SMB share using this software so I can't say for certain that it will work in that fashion, but it may be worth investigating if it resolves your issue.

The software isn't free unfortunately, but it is cheap, currently only $31.

http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/