# Sharing an HFS+ volume from Mavericks to Windows 8

Tags: macos, sharing, windows, hfs+

Does anyone know if it's at all possible to share an HFS+ volume from OSX 10.9 to Windows 8?

(I'd like to try and isolate any plugins and or extensions to the Windows platform, and keep my OSX box as clean and stock as possible.)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes - Mac OS will share files using SMB. Did you go to System Preferences, search for "File Sharing" and tick on the box? There's also built in help if you're not sure you have things enabled properly.

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't seem to see the drive in Windows. Perhaps this could be related to my other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/hosting-a-ntfs-drive-share-from-mavericks-to-windows-8

Comment: And you explicitly re-entered the password for the user accounts that will connect to SMB to generate the correct password hashes for windows to authenticate? ([Shown at the bottom of this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1549?viewlocale=en_US) )

Comment: i don't suggest doing it with your important files, use FAT32 instead, i once did this with very large files +20GB each and damaged my drive, my hard drive made a lot of noise after that, and finally didn't work (brand new macbook 2012) so i had to buy an SSD and never did that again (not sure if that was the cause though, just warning you with my experience)